# Best way to implement drawing of a line with the mouse

Tags: java, line, draw, 2d-games

I'm creating a game in Java where I need the user to be able to draw any kind of line on the screen, by holding and dragging the mouse across the screen.

The line could be any kind of curve. Total 'free form' line.

I also need to be able to detect collisions of a game-object with that line. And also, be able to 'pick apart' specific points on the line, in order to draw a vector between any two points on that line.

What would be a good way to go about doing that? Should I use a `Path2D` object? Or a `List` of `Line2D` objects? Or a `List` of `Point` objects? Anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When trying to do what you described, I found the following class very useful to base my code on:

http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/2d/Curve-java.html

Good Luck!

Comment: I think you missed the "'free form' line" part.

Comment: Totally did. My apologies. Updated with a link.

Comment: Yeah, got a little confused by the AWT stuff. Still, maybe the general idea could be useful. @BelgianMyWaffle, could you please explain the general concept of the code you shared?

Comment: @Prog: better to look at MadProgrammer's example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16909442/522444).

Comment: Also, [we don't really like answers mainly containing links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). It's better to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time I answer. Thanks for the feedback!